# Display custom label for User in rails_admin paper_trail history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

When I go to a `paper_trail` history page in rails_admin, I see User objects in the User column (`#<User:0x007f59a9...`).  Is there a way to configure this to use one of the User attributes?  I thought I could use `object_label_method` but I don't seem to be having any luck.

Update:

I thought this was purely a display issue but `paper_trail` is actually storing Strings like `#<User:0x007f59a9...` in the `whodunnit` column of the versions table rather than IDs.  I have overridden `user_for_paper_trail` in `ApplicationController` and while this successfully logs versions with User IDs in my frontend app, it does not in rails_admin.  According to [this thread](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/929), rails_admin should see my custom method because "RailsAdmin::ApplicationController inherits from your ::ApplicationController".  Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can get `paper_trail` to store User IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More digging revealed that this is a known problem with some combinations of versions of the gems.  [Here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/2187) is a recent rails_admin pull request that addresses it.  [Here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2144) is a more complete description of the issue.

For now, I'm monkey patching in the fix by putting the following code in `config/initializers/rails_admin_user_for_paper_trail.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin::ApplicationController.module_eval do
  def user_for_paper_trail
    _current_user.try(:id) || _current_user
  end
end
```

For reference, I'm using `paper_trail` 3.0.6, `rails_admin` 0.6.6 and Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: you can add `config.before_filter :set_paper_trail_whodunnit` to activeadmin initializer and then use :user_for_paper_trail from application controller