# Customising Whodunnit information for Rails Admin using Paper Trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I have been able to correctly append the name of a user into the Whodunnit field for actions by adding this to my `application_controller`

```
def user_for_paper_trail                                                                                     
    current_user ? current_user.name : 'Public user'                                                           
end
```

This works fine.

If a user makes a change using Rails Admin however, the whodunnit is still set to the user id.

Is there a method I can call that would tell paper trail what detail I want to store when a record is being updated via Rails Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RailsAdmin` has had some issues with this. You will find the following helpful: [Display custom label for User in rails_admin paper_trail history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588690/display-custom-label-for-user-in-rails-admin-paper-trail-history).

Also, because the field is supposed to store IDs (even though it's a string field), I'd keep the IDs and store something nonsensical for the `'Public user'` such as `'0'` (referenced by a constant, of course). I would then override the `whodunnit` method to return `'Public user'` in case `super == '0'`.

That approach would be particularly helpful if you already have a bunch of versions with IDs in their `whodunnit` fields or if you have multiple users with the same name.

P.S. To quickly confirm that `RailsAdmin` is completely ignoring / not ignoring the controller method you've defined, just force-raise an error in the method.

Comment: Thanks for this! 

Our use case is purely for reporting which is why we felt confident changing the id to the name. The team using it find the IDs to be useless as they just need to know who to go and speak to about an edit.

We will never be reverting changes back with paper trail or doing anything where the whodunnit will actually be used.